# How to get filename from camera using imagePickerController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am new in Swift and I am not able to get filename when I am using camera. My code is like this

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            
            if let url = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.imageURL] as? URL {
                self.fileName = url.lastPathComponent
                self.ImageFormat = url.pathExtension
                
                let fullNameArr = fileName.components(separatedBy: ".")
                let firstName = fullNameArr[0] //First
                ImagePathforServer = firstName
                
            }
            
            print(self.fileName)
            print(self.ImageFormat)
            
            imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                let base64Str = "\(self.convertImageToBase64(image: image))"
                self.base64forImageUpload = base64Str

            }
            
        } else {
            print("There was an error picking the image")
        }
    }
```

I am able to get filename from library but not from camera.

Comment: Perhaps the image straight from the camera doesn't have a filename, because it's not saved as a file anywhere yet.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

From the library, the image is saved inside photos/disk. But when you take a photo from it's not saved anywhere until you save it somewhere. You can save that image to the Documents folder to get the path or you can save it inside photos.

example to save image inside Documents Directory:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIImage {

func saveToDocuments(filename:String) {
    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(filename)
    if let data = self.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) {
        do {
            try data.write(to: fileURL)
        } catch {
            print("error saving file to documents:", error)
        }
    }
}

}
```

//Retrive the image from directory

```
 public static func loadImageFromDocumentDirectory(fileName: String) -> UIImage? {

    let documentsUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!;
    let fileURL = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    do {
        let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
        return UIImage(data: imageData)
    } catch {}
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Where to define loadImageFromDocumentDirectory this function and how to call it?